# Limiting ForeignKey fields in admin when editing section/site Django

Tags: django, django-admin

how to limit the number of foreign key fields in Django next time editing? 
example : I've a model Project and Images, Images has many to one relation to Project. Project includes title, slug, description, etc.

`models.py`

```
class Images(models.Model):
    image = ImageField(upload_to='project/')
    multi_image = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='other_images')
```

`admin.py`

```
class ImagesInline(AdminImageMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    model = Images
    extra = 3
```

I can register this class using inline.

before saving 
[image: before saving]

after saving and visiting again for editing

[image: editing]

I want to remove those extra empty image fields when I go for editing, I mean I don't want to show them anymore. 
Is it possible?

Comment: extra=1, max_num=3

Answer (score 0):

[You can set a value `max_num` on ImagesInline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.max_num), which will limit the maximum number of inlines displayed. If believe if this number is set and you already have some filled in relationships, it will fill it to the max number (So in the case of your screenshot, if you set it to 3, it will show 1 filled in relationship and 2 blanks.)

Comment: In my case, i) extra=3 shows 3 emty fields that right but ii) when I go for an edit it then too show 3 empty extra fields at that time in ii) part I don't want to show those fields. max_num just limits the max fields. is there any way ?

Comment: No, as far as I’m aware, that’s no built in way to achieve this. Best way to do this would be to customize the admin template.